# Code that hasn't been executed yet effects context above it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have the following on line 163:

```
this.setState(data)
```

Then right below it I have this:

```
(function(data){
  setTimeout(() => {
    // do some stuff
  }, 5)
}).call(this, data)
```

When I comment out the latter, it all works fine. When I leave it there, for some reason I get an undefined error coming from line 163, saying this.setState is not a function.

Also when I simply replace the second snippet with

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // do stuff
  }, 5)
```

again, it works fine (except for the fact that sometimes the data variable isn't what it should be... not always though, weird).

How is this happening? How can code that hasn't been executed yet make `this.setState` undefined? I even checked in the debugger and this is set to what it should be right before it throws the error... am I missing something here?

Comment: _"I even checked in the debugger"_ - Begs the question: Why? Setting a breakpoing in the function body could answer your question...

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark here but you may want to consider passing a copy of your `data` rather than a reference into `setState` - a quick and dry approach would be doing `{ ...data }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the second code block (an IIFE) is surrounded by parentheses. There is an unterminated statement before it. Hence, the JS interpreter will call the result of `this.setState()` which is not a function, resulting in an error.

Adding a semicolon at the end of `this.setState()` should solve it.

`this.setState();`